# malloc() function crashes

Tags: c, pointers, crash, malloc

I have a program, where I am reading Data from a txt-File.
Its basically a (fixed in first line) number of integers in every line.

Example:

```
    11
    1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I can read those into an int-Pointer without a problem and passing this pointer to another function:

```
    Term initTerm(int size, int* Exponents){
         Term a = newTerm(size)
         //Some code to insert the int's of the pointer into the pointer of Term
         return a
    }
```

Whereas

```
    typedef struct Term{
        int* Exponents; 
        int size;       //Number of ints in the Exponents-pointer
    }Term;
```

and

```
    Term newTerm(int size){
        Term res;
        res.Exponents = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        //Check for NULL
        res.size = size;
        return res;
    }
```

The Problem is now the following: 
After 194 perfectly correct invocations of initTerm, the 195th call crashes the program. 
Debugging made sure, the failure occured in the malloc-call (not at the check for validity of the pointer returned). 
If I change the ordering of the code where I invoke initTerm, I just could reach Term ~300, same goes for some compiling-Flags such as -O3 or -pg (I am using gcc-Compiler), changes the number of correct invocations.

I already found out, that malloc() crashes, if the head, that is additionally allocated, is corrupted, usually provoked by multithreading. Since my program is perfectly single-Threaded in every line of code, I am wondering, what I can do, to read through the whole file (currently 710 Terms, possibly growing to several MegaByte)

**EDIT:** 
Thanks for the help, I found the problem.
You were right about the malloc-Failure being just the symptom, as I just realized that the Buffer, I use to get the lines from the file into, was never resetting and so was starting to wander around anywhere in my RAM. Copying the address, malloc returns, to a pointer and resetting the Buffer after extracting the numbers, works fine now!

Comment: I bet you are accessing (writing to) an element out-of-bounds at some other part in your code. Check all indexes used to access the allocated array. You might want to use a function `setExponent(struct Term base, int index, int value)` and use that, **with checks**, instead of direct access.

Comment: The Error occurs in the executing of malloc, not in accessing the ints. That is what debugging with printf in newTerm() shows. 
I will do the setExponent-Function nevertheless, thank for that idea!

Comment: @T-r4X you state the error occurs in the execution of malloc, however what pmg means I think (and what I believe based on your description) is this is wrong -- rather, the _symptom_ occurs in the execution of malloc, and the _error_ occurs much earlier without immediate consequences. As pmg suggests, you are likely writing into a memory space you don't have rights to, which corrupts structures used internally by malloc, which leads to the crash.

Comment: A crash in malloc is almost always the result of an earlier error writing outside the bounds of allocated memory.  One of the main reasons heap corruption bugs are hard to track down is that the site of the obvious symptom (the crash) is generally nowhere near the location of the root cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like standard memory corruption through buffer-overflow, use of freed memory, use of wild pointers or the like, though it is not in the presented code.
`malloc()` will only crash if the bookkeeping data-structures are corrupted (likely) or the implementation is buggy (extremely unlikely if you didn't roll your own).

Use a debug_malloc with additional checks or a checker like valgrind. You might consider inserting a full heap check at interesting points.

Comment: Does buffer-overflow occur on a deterministic basis? It doesn't matter, how much RAM is used by other programs, TaskManager doesn't show any MemoryLeak or anything for that matter

Comment: Depends on whether your code is deterministic until then ;-) Anyway, just institute a regim of full heap checks, and use a debug heap.

Comment: Buffer overflows have nothing to do with memory leaks or with ram used by external programs. They can be deterministic or not, depending on the code that performs them. Sometimes they're caused by undefined behavior, others they're caused by merely overlooking something simple. Your best bet is to use a memory debugger tool, such as Valgrind if your system support that (most, if not all systems, have something available).